# options dialog in React Native Paper

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

I want to implement the options dialog from [React Native Paper](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/4.0/dialog.html):
[image]
However, the example code ([link to example code](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/4.0/dialog.html)) from React Native Paper is different.
There doesn't seem to be functionality in React Native Paper to create the options dialog. 
The best suitable option I know of is https://github.com/react-native-picker/picker, but that's not really the UI I'm looking for.
Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the sample source code of react-native-paper into this:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Button, Paragraph, Dialog, Portal, Provider, RadioButton, Text} from 'react-native-paper';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('Option 1');
  const showDialog = () => setVisible(true);

  const hideDialog = () => setVisible(false);

  return (
    <Provider>
      <View>
        <Button onPress={showDialog}>Show Dialog</Button>
        <Portal>
          <Dialog visible={visible} onDismiss={hideDialog}>
            <Dialog.Title>Choose an option</Dialog.Title>
            <Dialog.Content>
             <RadioButton.Group onValueChange={newValue => setValue(newValue)} value={value}>
              <View>
               <Text>Option 1</Text>
               <RadioButton value="option 1" />
              </View>
              <View>
               <Text>Option 2</Text>
               <RadioButton value="option 2" />
              </View>
              <View>
               <Text>Option 3</Text>
               <RadioButton value="option 3" />
              </View>
             </RadioButton.Group>
            </Dialog.Content>
            <Dialog.Actions>
              <Button onPress={hideDialog}>OK</Button>
              <Button onPress={hideDialog}>Cancel</Button>
            </Dialog.Actions>
          </Dialog>
        </Portal>
      </View>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```